# Problemas ao rodar JavaScript asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core

Copiei umas pastas contendo scripts css e javascript para o wwwroot esses arquivos estão sendo referenciados no meu Shared/_layout.

NO canto superior da minha janela do Visual studio 2017, está aparecendo a mensagem: "O JavaScript Language Service foi desabilitado para os seguintes projetos: Nome_do_Meu_Projeto".

Quando eu compilo a app, a página aparece em branco, pois ele não executada nada de css e javascript... Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Pode ver o console do seu navegador quando carrega a pagina pra ver se da algum erro?

Comment: Infelizmente o seu projeto está bulgado porque os arquivos estão faltando e os que forma inseridos estão errados. Dá uma olhada nisso e pegue o que realmente precisa tem muita coisa naquelas pastas que não serão utilizadas, não tem como ajudar, só se você inserir o projeto que está utilizando para fazer o seu layout!